# Using command line to lowercase all text in all files?

Tags: command-line, ssh

I've been trying out several commands such as

```
dd if=*.xml of=*.xml conv=lcase
```

to mass all the content of all the xml files in my folder to being lowercase.  The folders filenames are already lowercase, I'm trying to change all the actual content to being lower case as well.

Can someone post the command to do this or tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in *.xml; do tr A-Z a-z < $i > tmp && mv tmp $i; done
```

If your file names contain unusual characters (whitespace, newlines, control characters, etc), you may have to quote "$i", but since you say the names are all lowercase, I'm assuming that is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sed` to edit files in place which will save you from writing a loop.

```
sed  -ri 's/.+/\L\0/' *.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for:

```
sed -ie 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' *.xml
```

I see that you've tagged your question with ssh. You didn't specify it, but does this mean that you want to run this command at the end of an ssh command? I that case, you will need to escape out the asterisks, as they're supposed to be interpreted remotely, like this:

```
sed -ie 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' \*.xml
```